# Hex value to custom decimal value

Tags: c++, hex, decimal

I got 8-bit value that I need to convert by specific rules. Rules are

- Value Type is unsigned
- Step is 0.1 (in documentation stays *Res*, I'm not sure what that means)
- Offset is -10 (also not very clear to me)
- Value range is [-10, +15.5] (included both)

My idea was to represent it as `uint8_t` and if `number <= 155` return value is `(number*0.1)` and if `number > 155` return value is `(-number*0.1)`, but I'm not sure if it fits all standards(res, offset...).

Comment: So you need to design an encoding to store fixed-point 1-decimal numbers from -10 to 15.5 into 8 bits. I that it ? Also, please pick one single language.

Comment: Yes, that's the title I couldn't think of. I've edited question.

Comment: _"I got 8-bit hex value"_ Are you sure it's a "hex value"? Do you know what a "hex value" is?

Comment: Oops, editing again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Res` is probably `resolution`, meaning that each "step" of input integer (value 1) equals to `0.1`

`Offset` describes what effective corresponds to `0` of 8-bit input integer

So: in range [-10, +15.5] theres exactly 255 values, with 0.1 step, meaning each 8-bit integer have corresponding value from that range

to get it just do `(number * res) + offset`